# 'dict' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: django

i am sending a post request from my frontend when i check it on my browser the successfully sent request looks like this `user:"username"` but when i try to print it in my `views.py` i get `dict` object has no attribute 'user'

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def sendmail(request):
    print(request.data.user)
```

note that `request.data` looks like this `{'user': 'username'}`, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What does `print(request.data)` gives you ? What about `request.data.get("user")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a python problem. The keys in dictionaries are not called like object attributes.

So the code should look like this:

```
print(request.data['user'])
```